# Pockethernet or other network testing tool

Tags: networking

I am looking for a network testing tool for work that doesn't break the bank. I use the cheap wire mappers for checking pairs on runs once terminated, but I want something with more features such as wire length, link testing, port blinking, and network testing (internet accessibility and the like).

I currently have to lug around my laptop with me (or my tiny WAP to use my phone) to test and verify actual connectivity, but having an all in one tool would be great.

My budget is around $300 and I found Pockethernet which ticks all the boxes plus more for what I need that is in my price range.

Are there any other tools that have the same feature set? I am having troubles finding them.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't trust cheap devices! years ago I burned a router from cheap testing device..